# Multiple Post Vlaue through loop

Tags: php, mysql

Kindly explain three multiple text box value want to insert into mysql database

```
<input type="text" name="name1[]" />
<input type="text" name="name2[]" />
<input type="text" name="name3[]" />
```

i want post this values via loop and insert into mysql

kindly explain below single foreach loop is possible

```
    foreach($_POST['name'],$_POST['name2'],$_POST['name3']  as $key => $value)
{

INSERT INTO (name1, name2, name3)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I answer the question the way I understand it. Here is an example of something similar in logic:
HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="some_name[]" value="value1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="some_name[]" value="value2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="some_name[]" value="value3" />
```

This way you form an array of $_POST['some_name']

And then in php you loop through it and insert the data in a MySQL table with a single column `name`

```
foreach($_POST['some_name'] as $name)
{
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `table` VALUES `name` = '$name'");
}
```

Of cource this is just a descriptive example of what I consider to be the question (as it is not very clear)